What is the recommended tool or platform for API stress testing? It needs to support at least concurrent stress testing
It would be best if the platform or tool is relatively popular and widely recognized, and it should at least support concurrent stress testing.
I tried Postman, but it only supports serial testing, not parallel.
I also tried JMeter, but the experience wasn't very good.
Are there any other tools or platforms that you would recommend for API concurrent stress testing?
tip: My friend recommended Burp Suite to me. while it does fit the bill, isn't it generally used for penetration testing? Do you actually use Burp Suite for API stress testing?

In no particular order, here are some useful alternatives to JMeter, which all support "concurrent stress testing". They can each be used to script, schedule, execute, & report synthetic loads for APIs as well as for web servers.

Gatling
Locust
Grinder

I do agree that JMeter is peculiar, but once you get used to it, it can get the job done, and it's got good community support. I particularly appreciate the wide range of plugins available.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

K6.io is a standard tool for this.
This is a paid tool, though it has a free tier.
The way this tool works is:

You deploy the application
You write some test definitions
The tests are executed on K6's infrastructure.

You can write all sorts of tests, including long running soak tests (good for testing for memory leaks), stress tests (max load) etc. See documentation here. 
